# Are ngrx effects triggered again after state updates?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

In my Angular project I have this ngrx effect, which triggers a new SearchAction:

```
createSearchWithNewLimit$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(pageLimitChangedAction),
      concatLatestFrom(() => [this.store.select(selectSearchParams)]),
      switchMap(([{limit}, currSearchParams]) => {
        if(currSearchParams) {

          const searchParams = { ...currSearchParams, limit};

          return of(searchAction({searchParams}));
        }
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )
  })
```

Additionally, The SearchAction reducer updates the searchParams in the state (the one that is being retrieved in this effect in **this.store.select(selectSearchParams)**).

Does this mean that each time the SearchAction is dispatched, this effect will be triggered since it is using **this.store.select(selectSearchParams)**? and if so, how would this not cause an infinite loop? Or is it evaluated only once?
Thanks

Comment: No, it's not a `combineLatest`. `concatLatestFrom` is a custom operator from ngrx https://ngrx.io/api/operators/concatLatestFrom and it'll just "attach" the last value of the observable to the main stream, but won't re trigger the main stream if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concatLatestFrom` reads the current value from the store and passes that value down to the next operator. It won't retrigger the effect when it's value is changed.

It's comparable with RxJS's `withLatestFrom` operator, with the difference that `concatLatestFrom` is lazily evaluated.

For more info see the docs:

> Note: For performance reasons, use a flattening operator like concatLatestFrom to prevent the selector from firing until the correct action is dispatched.

- https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state
- https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators#concatlatestfrom
- https://ngrx.io/api/operators/concatLatestFrom

Comment: Thank you, you helped me solve a bug I was stuck on for days